# How to refresh browser page using Tornado

Tags: tornado

I am looking to refresh the browser page while my tornado script is executing a task. In the beginning, I would like to keep it simple but then perhaps add to it.

So, here are the steps I envision: 
a. User enters the Tornado URL in the browser. 
b. Clear browser page & display "processing ...." in the browser.
c. Since my Tornado script takes time to process data, it comes back after 1-2 minutes, and I want to display the result followed by self.finish().

Here is the snippet of code:

```
 class Application(tornado.web.Application):
def __init__(self):
    handlers = [
        (r"/", HomeHandler),
        (r"/iq", iQHandler),
    ]
    super(Application, self).__init__(handlers, default_handler_class=my404Handler)

class myBaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
    if status_code == 404:
        self.render("404.html")
    else:
        self.render("genericerror.html")

class my404Handler(myBaseHandler):
def prepare(self):
    raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)

class HomeHandler(myBaseHandler):
def get(self):
    self.render("home.html")

class iQHandler(myBaseHandler):
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def _initialize(self):
    # check if proper parameters are passed
    param1 = self.get_argument('media', None)
    if not param1:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)
    try:
        res = yield self._findfiles(param1)
    except Exception, e:
        print ("Error in _initialize() routine --> ", e)
        #raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(res)

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def _findfiles(self, justFileName):
    # find the file and lots of other processing to do
    # code hidden on purpose. 
    raise tornado.gen.Return(strValue)

@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    # clear browser page
    # show that we are processing
    response = yield self._initialize()
    # clear browser page again
    self.clear()
    self.finish(response)

def main():
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
http_server.listen(options.port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

I need help in the GET() routine. The clear() and finish() are working fine. I need help in the steps prior to the YIELD call. 
Thanks.